# Count pair-wise occurrences in a T-SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I count pair-wise occurrences in a SQL Server table? Please note that the order of the given sequence has to be accounted for and shouldn't be changed.

Original table:

```
    1 2 3 4
   --------
1 | A A A B
2 | A       # don't count
3 | B A A
4 | B       # don't count
```

Result:

```
1 | AA = 3
2 | AB = 1
3 | BB = 0
4 | BA = 1
```

In addition, the code has to work for large datasets.

**Edit**:

A pair in this context is a set of two values {x[ij], x[(i+1)j]}, where i=1,...,4 and j=1,...,4. Further, pairs that have the form `A null` or `B null` shouldn't be counted. Moreover, `null A` or `null B` can't happen, therefore they don't have to be accounted for.

Comment: How would you process a row like: `null A B null`?

Comment: The source table violates the rules of database normalization, no wonder it's difficult to query. I think you need to explain the significance of the individual rows and columns, you need to define the meaning of the word "pair" in your context, and why `A` and `B` count as a pair... This question needs a lot of definition.

Comment: You still don't explain why `A` and `B` count as a pair. Also, rows 2, 3 of your table seem to contain `null` values. Can you show us the pairs forms for these two rows according to your definition?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thank you, Giorgos! I saw my mistake and have added the information in question. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by why `A` and `B` count as a pair? It is so, because I (!) defined it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374429)**

```
CREATE TABLE #tab([1] NVARCHAR(100), [2] NVARCHAR(100),
                  [3]  NVARCHAR(100), [4] NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab
VALUES ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B') ,('A' , NULL ,NULL ,NULL  )   
      ,('B' ,'A' ,'A', NULL),('B',  NULL, NULL, NULL);

WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT pair = [1] + [2] FROM #tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pair = [2] + [3] FROM #tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pair = [3] + [4] FROM #tab   
), cte2 AS
(
  SELECT [1] AS val FROM #tab
  UNION ALL SELECT [2] FROM #tab
  UNION ALL SELECT [3] FROM #tab
  UNION ALL SELECT [4] FROM #tab
), all_pairs AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT a.val + b.val AS pair
  FROM cte2 a
  CROSS JOIN cte2 b
  WHERE a.val IS NOT NULL and b.val IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT a.pair, result = COUNT(c.pair)
FROM all_pairs a
LEFT JOIN cte c
  ON a.pair = c.pair
GROUP BY a.pair;
```

How it works:

1. `cte` create all pairs (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)
2. `cte2` get all values from column
3. `all_pairs` create all possible pairs of values `AA, AB, BA, BB`
4. Final use grouping and `COUNT` to get number of occurences.

**EDIT:**

You can concatenate result as below:

**[LiveDemo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374436)**

```
...
, final AS
(
SELECT a.pair, result = COUNT(c.pair), rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.pair)
FROM all_pairs a
LEFT JOIN cte c
  ON a.pair = c.pair
GROUP BY a.pair
)
SELECT rn, [result] = pair + ' = ' + CAST(result AS NVARCHAR(100))
FROM final
```

Comment: @JimBoy See my updated answer and demo 2, I added some formating

Comment: Thank you, lad2025! This is a really nice solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

I just want to point out a pretty easy way to *express* this logic:

```
with vals as (
      select 'A' as val union all select 'B'
     )
     pairs as (
      select t1.val as val1, t2.val as val2
      from vals t1 cross join vals t2
    )
select p.*,
       (select count(*)
        from original
        where [1] = val1 and [2] = val2 or
              [2] = val1 and [3] = val2 or
              [3] = val1 and [4] = val2
       ) as cnt
from pairs p
order by cnt desc;
```

This doesn't have great performance characteristics, that is actually easily fixed by using three subqueries and indexes on the data columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (
    select 1 as id, 'A' as [1], 'A' as [2], 'A' as [3], 'B' as [4]
    union all select 2 , 'A', NULL,NULL,NULL
    union all select 3 , 'B', 'A','A',NULL
    union all select 4 , 'B',NULL,NULL,NULL
    )
    , Vals as (
        select 'AA' as Val
        union all select 'AB' 
        union all select 'BB'
        union all select 'BA'
    )
    , UNPVT as (
        /*UNPIVOT to convert the columns to be rows*/
        SELECT id , VAL + LEAD(VAL) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SEQ) as Code
        FROM (
        select ID,[1],[2],[3],[4] from cte
        ) P 
        UNPIVOT (Val FOR Seq IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
        ) AS UNPVT
    )
    select Vals.Val, count(UNPVT.Code)  from UNPVT right join Vals on UNPVT.Code = Vals.Val
    group by Vals.Val
```

CTE: contains your data.
Vals: contains the returned code.
UnPVT: to convert the columns to be rows.